# As an older student, is it better to finish my degree or go straight into studying physics now?

Tags: soft-question, education

I'm a 23 year old going through a very early mid-life crisis, and considering a career change to physics. I would be very greatful for any advice **:)**

I'm currently studying medicine, but I've realized that I don't have *any* interest in working as a doctor, and what truly interests me is - you guessed it - physics. Even though I only have 1.5 years left until my diploma, I'm seriously considering dropping out if I can get accepted into a (hopefully tutition free, as I'm now a broke @ss student) physics course.

I don't know that I would officially have even a bachelor of science if I were to drop out now, since I'm in a European university that accepts students straight out of high school. But the idea of forcing myself to go through another 1.5 years of hard work while I'm slowly dying inside, doesn't sound like too much fun.

So now that I've shared with you the long and boring history of my student life, does anyone have any advice on whether it would be worth finishing my medical diploma - would it be any help for getting into a physics undergraduate program, or considered at all when I apply for a physics job/teaching/research position if I eventually get a degree in physics?

Having read that physics graduates can often have difficulties finding jobs, I worry that I'll be a happy  but homeless physics graduate  (ideally, I'd like a future job at a university since my interests in physics are not very industrial). Somehow I don't think that being an oldie graduate compared to the young brilliant graduates would greatly increase my job chances. But well, didn't want to give up on my dream yet without asking you physicists out there for what prospects I would face in reality.

Huge thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: Perhaps [Academia.StackExchange](http://academia.stackexchange.com) might be better suited for this question? Or maybe the [physics chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) (requires 20 rep).

Comment: Do not be discouraged by the close, there are people here very strict with the rules ready to jump and impose them. ( they do not think you may not even be allowed to enter chat mode with just 1 as reputation) Lets hope you will get some answers in the comments. You do not state whether you will try for a scholarship to the US, for example. There are many colleges and universities there that consider foreign students , look at the courses they have followed and position them in the appropriate year for a bachelors for physics.

Comment: In the US case you will not have a problem with not finishing the MD degree. To have a chance for a scholarship you should have excellent grades in the courses that have to do with physics and mathematics. You should start looking now. If you have excellent grades the ivy league colleges look for exceptional foreign students. Good luck

Comment: Thank you anna v for your kind reply. I will look into US scholarships (so far I found a scholarship opportunity in a country nearby that I will apply to)

Comment: There's always radiology... At some level it involves both advanced physics/math and medicine. E.g., PET scanning involves positron/electron annihilation inside the human body and subsequent detection of high energy x-rays to create maps of internal organs, etc. CT scanning involves x-ray absorption as well as some fancy transformations to reconstruct 3d densities from stacks of 3d images. It pays well too... unlike physics.